# Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

> 'Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>
> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
>
> This is my error. I searched a lot but I can't able to find a solution
>   for this please help me someone
>
> In the Console tab it has given Info:

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\;C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32(1)\eclipse;
```

> All the traces of Console are here. Please help me.
>
> Jul 17, 2014 4:51:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
>   INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\;C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32(1)\eclipse;
>   Jul 17, 2014 4:51:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
>   SEVERE: Begin event threw error
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.findMethods(IntrospectionUtils.java:753)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.setProperty(IntrospectionUtils.java:286)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.setProperty(IntrospectionUtils.java:275)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin(SetAllPropertiesRule.java:67)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:555)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:598)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:449)
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.findMethods(IntrospectionUtils.java:753)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.setProperty(IntrospectionUtils.java:286)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.setProperty(IntrospectionUtils.java:275)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin(SetAllPropertiesRule.java:67)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:555)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:598)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:449)
>
> Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To resolve the issue related to "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance" you have to add a system property to the launch configuration of the tomcat server in eclipse.

```
 -Djava.library.path=[tomcat_home]\bin
```

as well `tcnative-1.dll 64/32 bit` download  and place it in bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

The message "The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path" is not an error.

From your logs, the error is :

```
4:51:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement 
SEVERE: Begin event threw error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
        javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Which means you are using java 6 to launch something compiled with java 7. 
Are you sure you are using tomcat7 and not tomcat8?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the eclipse tomcat server configuration. Open the server view, double click on you server to open server configuration. Then click to activate "Publish module contents to separate XML files". Finally, restart your server, the message must disappear.

This time page will come without any issues.

[image]